# Python. Сумма значений с одинаковым ключом

Tags: python

Всем привет, никак не могу разобраться, как в Python поcчитать сумму значений, которые имеют одинаковы ключи.

```
Допустим пользователь вводит: Миша 2
                              Гриша 1
                              Миша 1
На выходе мы должны получить: Миша 3
                              Гриша 1
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. Прикрепил фрагмент кода с вводом.

```
quantity = int(input('Введите число голосующих регионов:'))
votes = dict([input('Введите имя кандидата и количество голосов через пробел:').split() for i in range(quantity)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю воспользоваться методом словаря `get`, возвращая в случае отсутствия ключа 0.

***Пример:***

```py
quantity = int(input('Введите число голосующих регионов:'))

d = {}
for _ in range(quantity):
    k, v = input('Введите имя кандидата и количество голосов через пробел:').split()
    d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + int(v)

print(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно через `Counter` как-то так. Как совместить с вашим кодом надеюсь разберётесь:

```
from collections import Counter
l = [('Миша', '2'), ('Гриша', '1'), ('Миша', '1')]
c = Counter()
[c.update({k: int(v)}) for k,v in l]
print(c)
```

Вывод:

```
Counter({'Миша': 3, 'Гриша': 1})
```

Когда вы пытаетесь создать словарь из всего списка, значение с повторяющимся ключом просто затирает предыдущее значение.